# How to automatically scale input with static placeholder?

Tags: html, css, input

I've been used this hack to create a static placeholder in the `input`:

```
<div class="l_standard staticPlaceholder">
    <label for="alias" style="cursor: text;">site.com/</label>
    <input type="text" name="alias" id="alias" maxlength="15" />
</div>
```

But I need manually set a `width` for `input` to prevent breaking of this construction when resizing. How can I make this `input` like "rubber"?

Here is an example - http://jsfiddle.net/qKfqa/ Input field goes down and brake construction.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you mean?  Is there something wrong with the `placeholder` input attribute?

Comment: @Explosion Pills, here is an example - http://jsfiddle.net/qKfqa/ Input field goes down and brake construction.

Comment: How’s a common `label` a “static placeholder” …?

Comment: It`s need to looks like this - http://jsfiddle.net/qKfqa/3/ but input will be rubber(automatically scale to need width)

Comment: @ExplosionPills `placeholder` attribute doesn't work on IE <10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Table Cell

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/qKfqa/7/ (I've made box borders visible to demonstrate layout; resize pane to see "rubber" behavior).

This relies on a bit of a hack, i.e. setting one cell to 1px wide and relying on the behavior of `display:table-cell` to force it to the width needed.

I've added additional markup to serve as the "cells"; it may be possible to do this with fewer elements.

```
.staticPlaceholder {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 50%;
    display: table;
}
.staticPlaceholder > DIV {
    display: table-cell;
}
.staticPlaceholder > DIV:first-child {
    width: 1px;
}
```

<sub>Tested with IE8+, Chrome, FF</sub>

---

### Inline Block

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/qKfqa/5/

There is no dependency on the width of the placeholder text, i.e. it can be whatever you want. Nor does the width of the input matter.

```
.staticPlaceholder {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;

    /* important part */
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.staticPlaceholder input {
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;

    /* width can be anything you want */
    width: 200px;
}
```

If it works correctly, it should look like:

[image]

<sub>Tested with IE8+, Chrome, FF</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Just make `.staticPlaceHolder` wider. I changed it to `width: 300px;`: http://jsfiddle.net/qKfqa/1/

Comment: That`s wrong. Really width of `.staticPlaceHolder` is percentage and when i resize the window this block resizes too and input again goes down...

Answer (score 0):

`width: 100%;` on the input will make it fit to the width of the parent div, but borders/padding/margins may screw it up a bit so you may also want to add `box-sizing: border-box`.

http://jsfiddle.net/qKfqa/2/